# Should I create a button image in high resolution if the product needs to be low resolution?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, resolution, workflow, mobile

Should a mobile game button (say 72x72 pixels round one) be created in these exact dimensions or create it in a larger resolution and export a low resolution file? I think working with a larger one is much easier. How do professionals do this?

Comment: Hi Bombay, welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I took the liberty to copyedit your question a little and tweak the tags you used. If you think anything marred your question beyond recognition, feel free to roll it back or re-edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most professional way would be to make it in vector, so it is resolution independent. Then, export in any size you see fit.

You could try to do this is Photoshop as it has some vector tools that will scale when you change their size. If you have access to Illustrator or a similar vector editing program like Inkscape, that would be the superior option.

Having a vector (or very hi-res) source file ensures that you are able to export your assets at any desired size. For now, that button might just need to be 72 x 72 pixels, but what happens if it gets included in an ad banner 20 metres wide?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right about that. But is not Photoshop more suitable for designed icons? For an avatar maybe or an icon indicating some kind of magic shot. Maybe I should not ask for a button in the first place. For the icons like the image below, I think made in Photoshop. I wonder if they did these in PS, what should be the approach? [link](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C0G5UyFUAAA1Q6l.jpg)

Comment: That really depends on the style of your icons. From the link, I see that these use a lot of effects that are all attainable in Illustrator, but way easier to do in Photoshop. For this general case, instead of relearning a lot of stuff in Illustrator, I'd go for a hi-res .psd source file for each icon rather than Ai. Were I to do this from scratch, I'd still use Ai mostly, but I have a lot of experience with that app.